# IPEndPoint in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, udp, system.net

I am hoping that someone might be able to help me with some huge confusion I am running into.  I am working on porting an open source library so that I can use it within Windows Phone 8.  The three main areas that I have found which need to be refactored for Windows Phone are:
Replace Timer/Thread functions with Task/Async calls
Replace [Serializable] with....  I some articles save on this, just not remembering off the top of my head

And lastly, IP/UDP communications - specifically IPEndPoint and Socket.

Where I am getting confused is that I cannot seem to resolve IPEndPoint, even though from everything I can see online it is supposed to be supported.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/fc99e3e7-c8d3-4b3f-bd2d-cc5bf9b5c56e/get-local-ip-address-on-wifi?forum=wpdevelop

And some other examples from SO which I do not have the links to.

**What am I missing?**

Should I be using something different than IPEndPoint?

FYI: I was originally porting this library to a PCL but I was reading something somewhere that said IPEndPoint was available in Windows Phone 8 so I created a new Windows Phone Class Library project for this code - which is giving me the same results anyways.

Comment: Are you `using System.Net;` so that you can see `IPEndPoint` and `using System.Net.Sockets;` so that you can see `Socket`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.endpointpair.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to my specific question is that IPEndPoint and Socket classes are only available with a Windows Phone 8/8.1 Silverlight application - Not sure why the difference there.  So now that I have recreated my app as the Silverlight version I am able to resolve those references.

Once I have completed the work necessary to "migrate" this code to Windows Phone I will look into updating the code to use Windows.Networking as linked by Hans.